# Manual mounting of cifs works fine, but not in fstab

Tags: 12.10, mount, fstab, cifs

I have a mounting problem that drives me mad at the moment...

Using the manual mounting command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/shareName /media/shareName -o uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,username='domain/name',password=pw
```

I am able to mount my network share without any problem. But then, when I include the line

```
//192.168.1.1/shareName /media/shareName   cifs    uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,username='domain/name',password=pw   0   0
```

into `fstab` and execute then the command

```
sudo mount -a
```

I receive the error message

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

When I restart the computer the boot process is as it should be without any errors, but the share isn't mounted.

Does anybody know if this is a bug?! Or do I miss there something?

Thanks for reading this...

PS: I do not have any white spaces in the network share name or any 'weird' characters in the password. Also the `cifs-utils` are installed. The additional option `users` in the `fstab` didn't helped either. Of course I'll use later the `credential` file when the `fstab` entry works, at the moment I use the password in `fstab` just for testing purposes (and it didn't worked neither when I tried the credential file instead)...

PPS: I use Kubuntu 12.10, but I hope this doesn't matter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine looks like this - with a credential file as mentioned above, but with some other explicit options.

```
//192.168.1.2/photos /media/photos cifs credentials=/home/[credentialfile],iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[my userid],gid=[my groupid],nobootwait 0 0
```

Comment: My problem did not exist anymore (new installation), on the new computer I mounted them this way and it worked for me as well, so I accept this answer, to get this thread closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your username and domain separately and without the single quotes:

```
domain=MYDOMAIN,user=myusername
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a credential file. I had the same issue. Credential file worked like a charm.

Example for an `fstab` entry:

```
//192.168.1.100/music /media/Musik cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials 0 0
```